# How can I remove empty paragraph elements?

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk, wordprocessingml

I am trying to remove paragraphs that contains `"{Some Text}"`. The method below does just that, but I noticed that after I remove the paragraphs, there are empty paragraph elements left over.

How can I remove `<w:p />` elements programmatically?

Below is what I initially used to remove paragraphs.

```
 using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(file, true))
        {
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart;
            Document D = mainPart.Document;

            foreach (Paragraph P in D.Descendants<Paragraph>())
            {
                if (P.InnerText.Contains("{SomeText}"))
                {
                    P.RemoveAllChildren();
                    //P.Remove();   //doesn't remove
                }
            }
            D.Save();
        }
```

This is how the document.xml looks like afterwords:

```
<w:p />
<w:p />
<w:p />
<w:p />
<w:p />
<w:p />
<w:p />
```

Comment: Just a guess -- are you missing a "not"? As in `if ( ! P.InnerText.Contains("{SomeText}"))` ?

Comment: Are those 7 paragraphs the toplevel tags?

Comment: Yes, they are top level tags @rene

Comment: What do you mean, doesn't remove? Is there an error, or seems like a NO-OP?

Comment: Instead of `P.RemoveAllChildren` try `D.Remove(P);`

Comment: i updated my question. No there are no errors thrown. @jsn

Comment: D.Remove(P) = Error "No overload for method 'Remove' takes 1 argument" @acbod

Comment: The problem might be that you are trying to remove items from a collection as you enumerate it. Try `D.Descendants<Paragraph>().ToList()` in your `foreach` first and then `P.Remove()`.

Comment: Yeah sorry, try `D.RemoveChild<Paragraph>(P)` That should work according to the documentation @DesmondLost

Comment: Same issue persists @MattBurland

Comment: @DesmondLost: Really? Because I just tried it and it worked just fine.

Comment: 'System.InvalidOperationException' is thrown @acbod

Comment: Please read my question carefully, I am trying to remove `<w:p />` elements. @MattBurland

Comment: @DesmondLost: Yes, I understand that. You want to remove the paragraphs, but since that didn't work you just removed all the children. But that leaves you with a bunch of empty paragraphs in your document. What I suggested in my answer fixes the problem. `D.Remove(P)` threw an exception, which is actually the correct behavior. That's what `P.Remove()` in your original code *should* have done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here:

```
        foreach (Paragraph P in D.Descendants<Paragraph>())
        {
            if (P.InnerText.Contains("{SomeText}"))
            {
                P.Remove();   //doesn't remove
            }
        }
```

Is that you are trying to remove an item from the collection while you are still iterating it. For some strange reason, the OpenXML SDK doesn't actually throw an exception here, it just silently quits the `foreach` loop. Attaching a debugger and stepping through will show you that. The fix is simple:

```
        foreach (Paragraph P in D.Descendants<Paragraph>().ToList())
        {
            if (P.InnerText.Contains("{SomeText}"))
            {
                P.Remove();   //will now remove
            }
        }
```

By adding `ToList()` you are copying (shallow copy) the paragraphs to a separate list and iterating through that list. Now when you remove a paragraph it is removed from the `D.Descendants<Paragraph>()` collection, but not from your list and the iteration will continue.

Comment: While this seems like a logical answer, it is hard to believe it is quitting the loop.

Comment: @jsn: I know, it's odd, but it really does. If you attach the debugger and step through, as soon as it hits `P.Remove()` (in the first case) it will jump to the closing bracket of the loop and then the next statement. It really should throw an exception, but I guess somebody goofed on that.

Comment: You're right Matt, it does work. A little non-related, but is there a way to iterate through the document and remove all `<w:p />` elements (i.e. when you press enter when creating a doc)?

Comment: That gets all the empty paragraphs. `foreach (Paragraph P in D.Descendants<Paragraph>().Where(x => !x.HasChildren).ToList())` @DesmondLost

Comment: @DesmondLost: Remove all the empty ones? Or all paragraphs? Either way, it's just a case of changing (or removing) the condition in your loop.

Comment: That answer really helped me to remove some paragraphs from my template.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above helped me to create following code snippet which deletes paragraphs from begin to end (excluding begin and end). This approach is quite handy when you must use a template as input, but you do not want some parts of it in the output.

```
public void RemoveParagraphsFromDocument(string begin, string end)
{
    using (var wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(OutputPath, true))
    {
        var mainPart = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart;
        var doc = mainPart.Document;
        var paragraphs = doc.Descendants<Paragraph>().ToList();
        var beginIndex = paragraphs.FindIndex(par => par.InnerText.Equals(begin));
        var endIndex = paragraphs.FindIndex(par => par.InnerText.Equals(end));

        for (var i = beginIndex + 1; i < endIndex; i++)
        {
            paragraphs[i].Remove();
        }

        doc.Save();
    }
}
```